# Need help understanding tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected trained weights

Tags: tensorflow

I'm relatively new to neural nets and tensorflow in general.
In a course I'm taking, we constructed a cnn.  In simplistic terms, I think I can convey what is happening with some stripped down statements:

In the first tf.session(), the network is trained and parameters are stored to a python dictionary.  I monitor the cost and test/train accuracy during the training in Tensorboard, and I get very reasonable results.

```py
def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    ....
    model layers...
    ....
    z_out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(P2, 6, activation_fn=None)

    return z_out

def model(X_train, Y_train,...):
    ....
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()
        ....
        loop thru epochs and mini-batches...
        optimize parameters...
        parameters = sess.run(parameters)
    ....

    return parameters # python dict
```

Then in the second tf session, predictions are made using the trained parameters from the first tf session.

```py
def predict(X, parameters):

    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, 64, 64, 3))
    z3 = forward_propagation(x, parameters)
    a3 = tf.nn.softmax(z3, axis=1)
    p = tf.argmax(a3, axis=1)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        prediction = sess.run(p, feed_dict = {x: X})

    return prediction
```

But the second session requires sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) otherwise tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected() throws an error without it.  As a result, returned predictions are randomized and change for every run.  I strongly suspect the weights are randomized or not loaded properly.

When I run the command tf.trainable_variables(), I get this output:

```
    [<tf.Variable 'W1:0' shape=(4, 4, 3, 8) 
    dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'W2:0' shape=(2, 2, 8, 16) 
    dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'fully_connected/weights:0' shape=(64, 6) 
    dtype=float32_ref>,
     <tf.Variable 'fully_connected/biases:0' shape=(6,) 
    dtype=float32_ref>]
```

It appears the weight and bias are present as variables.

So my question is essentially this:  How can I get the function tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(P2, 6, activation_fn=None) to properly load the weights or respond even when performing the global variables initializer?  Am I seriously missing a process or steps?

I verified the problem lies in the fully connected function because when I removed this layer and just implemented z_out = tf.matmul(P2, W3) + b3  (where W3 and b3 were properly trained variables in the parameters dict), the behavior was normal and stable with expected predictions.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the trained weights somewhere in memory. Usually, `forward_propagation`, and `predict` are some methods of a python class, and `model` can be wrapped in the `__init__()` of that class. Moreover, keep the tensorflow variables as class attributes like that:`self.z_out = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(P2, 6, activation_fn=None)`

Then when you call `predict`, you'll call `forward_propagation(x, parameters)` which will reuse the already initialized and trained `self.z_out` layer. So you won't get any error thrown.

Right now, your current code just redefine brand new layers when you call `forward_propagation` and expects you to initialize these layers. Note that you should keep all layers in your object, not only the last layer (here the convolutional layers).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm afraid your solution is more advanced than I'm am at this point.  I know a little about about class objects and methods but not enough to figure all this out.  If you can post an example of your solution, maybe I can figure it out and give it a try.

Comment: Wait wait, you should definitely learn about classes and object BEFORE learning tensorflow.

Comment: The important part to understand is that when you call "forward_propagation" in "predict" you actually define a NEW GRAPH, hence new variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  I need to add tf.train.Saver().save at the end of training session.  Then during the prediction session, I need to add tf.train.Saver().restore.  I also found that the graph needs to be reset before the training starts and also before the variables are restored to ensure a clean slate.

```py
def model(X_train, Y_train,...):
    ....

    tf.reset_default_graph()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()
        ....
        loop thru epochs and mini-batches...
        optimize parameters...
        parameters = sess.run(parameters)
        save_path = tf.train.Saver().save(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
        print (f"Variables saved in path: {save_path}")
    ....
```

Then during prediction:

```py
def predict(X, parameters):

    tf.reset_default_graph()

    x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=(None, 64, 64, 3))
    z3 = forward_propagation(x, parameters)
    a3 = tf.nn.softmax(z3, axis=1)
    p = tf.argmax(a3, axis=1)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        tf.train.Saver().restore(sess, "/tmp/model.ckpt")
        prediction = sess.run(p, feed_dict = {x: X})

    return prediction
```

Comment: This does work but "restore" should be used when you want to load parameters from a different python process. In other words you are saving/loading data on/from disk whereas it is not necessary.